# OpenCV stereo matching inverted output

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, stereo-3d, stereoscopy

I am trying to get stereo matching working with artificial depth images. 
The matching seems to come out good (no occlusions) but inverted( black = close, white = far)

```
int main()
{
    Mat img1, img2, g1, g2;
    Mat disp, disp8;
    img1 = imread("W:/GoogleDrive/UDK/Croped_left/4.png");
    img2 = imread("W:/GoogleDrive/UDK/Croped_left/1.png");

    cvtColor(img1, g1, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cvtColor(img2, g2, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    StereoBM sbm;
    sbm.state->SADWindowSize = 9;
    sbm.state->numberOfDisparities = 16;
    sbm.state->preFilterSize = 5;
    sbm.state->preFilterCap = 61;
    sbm.state->minDisparity = -39;
    sbm.state->textureThreshold = 507;
    sbm.state->uniquenessRatio = 0;
    sbm.state->speckleWindowSize = 0;
    sbm.state->speckleRange = 8;
    sbm.state->disp12MaxDiff = 1;
    sbm(g1, g2, disp);

    normalize(disp, disp8, 0, 255, CV_MINMAX, CV_8U);

    imshow("left", img1);
    imshow("right", img2);
    imshow("disp", disp8);

    waitKey(0);

    return(0);
}
```

These are the images I am using [4.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jICE.png) and [1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIEWt.png)

And the output I get is this: [image]

Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Try using [bitwise_not()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-not) function, it inverts all bytes on your image (white to black, black to white and so on). I've never had experience with stereo images, not sure if its possible, but read about it, it may help you. I use this function to invert Mat images.

Comment: The **depth** values are not inverted. Black values have **low** distance and **low** pixel values, while while pixels have **high** depth and **high** pixel values! Maybe you just have mixed up the terms?

Comment: Well yes depth does get calculated correctly but it's being represented in the wrong way. 8 bit disparity maps usually use 255 to indicate white which is a pixel closer to the camera and 0 as black pixel furthest away from the camera. http://students.cec.wustl.edu/~jwaldron/559/project2/depthMaps/torus.jpg

Comment: I might be wrong, but you got the disparity, and not depth, right? You need to calculate depth for each pixel to get the precise info you are looking for - see this: https://www.ptgrey.com/KB/10102

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I did a work around using the suggestion by Dainius Šaltenis by inverting the image using the bitwise not operator in opencv and the removing all the pure white pixels.

```
//Bitwise_not to invert the images
bitwise_not(disp8, disp8);

//Loop through the images find all white pixels and replace with black
for (int i = 0; i < disp8.rows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < disp8.cols; j++)
        if (disp8.at<uchar>(i, j) > 254)
            disp8.at<uchar>(i, j) = 0;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you confused left and right. 4.png should be right/img2 and 1.png left/img1. (The picture with the object to the right is as seen from the left camera and vice versa.)

Comment: If I flip the images other way around i get quite bad results even after adjusting the values.

Comment: Strange, it seemed to work for me. Anyway, I'm glad you found a solution.